# Find nth Element - Function composition

Tags: clojure

I am currently reading the book "The Joy of Clojure", 2nd edition.
In Chapter 7 "Functional Programming", I came across the following function that was used to describe function composition.

```
(defn fnth [n]
  (apply comp
         (cons first
               (take (dec n) (repeat rest)))))

((fnth 5) '[a b c d e])
;=> e
```

I don't fully understand the mechanics of that function.
Trying to reproduce the inner scope without using `comp`, the function produces a repeating list:

```
(take (dec 5) (repeat (rest '[a b c d e])))
;=> ((b c d e) (b c d e) (b c d e) (b c d e))
```

What is the point of attaching `first` to that repeating list by using `comp`?
Is this also the last part of the function list which is fed into `comp`?

```
(first (take (dec 5) (repeat (rest '[a b c d e]))))
=> (b c d e)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

The `fnth` function works by constructing a sequence of the form `(first rest rest ... rest)` i.e. `first` followed by n - 1 `rest`s. It then composes them into a single function by `apply`ing `comp`. For `(fnth 5)` this is

```
(apply comp (first rest rest rest rest))
```

When the result function is called on the vector `[a b c d e]` the resulting application is

```
(first (rest (rest (rest (rest [a b c d e])))))
```

i.e. the first element of the 4th tail of the input sequence.

Your attempted reconstruction only calls `rest` once and then `reapeat`s the returned sequence instead.

Comment: I see. The authors used that approach as well. This means `cons` attaches `first` to the list of functions before the complete list is fed into `comp` for evaluation, correct?

Comment: @GitCrush - Yes that's right. `((comp f g) x)` is `(f (g x))` so putting `first` at the front of the generated sequence means it will be the last function applied to the input. The resulting composition therefore returns the first element of the n-1th tail of the input sequence.

Answer (score 5):

This `fnth` does not (itself) return the nth item of a collection, but rather produces a function that does so.

What function should it produce to get the 1st item?

```
(defn nth-1 [coll]
    (first coll))
```

What function should it produce to get the 2nd item?

```
(defn nth-2 [coll]
    (first (rest coll)))
```

What function should it produce to get the 3rd item?

```
(defn nth-3 [coll]
    (first (rest (rest coll))))
```

So there's a pattern!  But the nesting would be a challenge for `fnth`.

An equivalent formulation for `(first (rest (rest x)))` is `((comp first rest rest) x)`.  Now we can write nth-3 as

```
(defn nth-3 [coll]
    ((comp first rest rest) coll))
```

With this approach `fnth` is easier to write.  But it would be easier still if we rewrote `(comp first rest rest)` as `(apply comp [first rest rest])`.  There!  Now `fnth` needs is to make a list of first + the right number of rest's, and apply comp to that list.